# Many Columns in One Table JOIN one reference table

Tags: sql, inner-join, dbforge

I am using DBForge Query Builder

I have one table with a number of columns which contain abbreviations.
Another table contains the descriptions for the abbreviations.

What is a query to replace the abbreviations with their descriptions?

I tried a number of joins without any success.

T1

```
ID  Date    Type    Cat Sub Cat
1   01/09/18    E   F   L
2   05/09/18    Cc  F   D
3   06/09/18    Cc  C   Dr
4   08/09/18    Cc  C   Sh
5   08/09/18    E   C   Sh
```

T2

```
Code    Des
E   Eft Payment
Cc  Credit Card
F   Food
C   Clothes
B   Breakfast
L   Lunch
D   Dinner
Sh  Shirt
Dr  Dress
```

Desired Output

```
ID  Date    Type D  Cat D   Sub Cat D
1   01/09/18    Eft Payment Food    Lunch
2   05/09/18    Credit Card Food    Dinner
3   06/09/18    Credit Card Clothes Dress
4   08/09/18    Credit Card Clothes Shirt
5   08/09/18    Eft Payment Clothes Shirt
```

Comment: You may be missing that you need to join to the `T2` table three times, once for each code that you wish to convert to a description.

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on [[ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the downvote mouseover text. Show what parts you can do & explain re being stuck. This is just asking for others to do your homework. Googling many clear phrasings of your question/problem will give many faq hits.

Comment: @MirzaObaid I rolled back your edit that improved nothing & should have removed noise. Image "alt text" to be replaced should be text that says what the image say s& an image should be inserted via the image button that makes that text invisible until requested. Normal text should present an image if necessary. But this image is redundant & should never have been there because it's an image of text & should be removed because the poster gave its content in text. Except the text should be initialization code as part of a [mre]. And "Ok. Very new so, please be kind." should have been removed.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below using multiple join by T2 with different alias

```
select 
   a.ID, a.date,
   b.Des as TypeD, 
   c.Des as CatD,
   d.Des as SubCatD
from T1 a inner join T2 b on a.type=b.code
inner join T2 c on a.Cat=c.code
inner join T2 d in a.SubCat=d.code
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use multiple instances of the T2 table:

```
select t1.id, t1.date, typ.des as type_d,ca.des as cat_d,subca.des as sub_cat_d from T1 t1 
inner join T2 typ on t1.type=typ.code 
inner join T2 ca on t1.cat = ca.code 
inner join T2 subca  on t1.subcat = subca.code;
```

Try this...

Answer (score 0):

I will assume the columns of T1 are (`ID, Date, Type, Cat, SubCat`)

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.Date, T2Type.Des, T2Cat.Des, T2SubCat.Des
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 T2Type   ON T1.Type   = T2Type.Code
        INNER JOIN T2 T2Cat    ON T1.Cat    = T2Cat.Code
        INNER JOIN T2 T2SubCat ON T1.SubCat = T2SubCat.Code
```

Answer (score 0):

We’d recommend the following solution:

```
SELECT t_type_code.id,
       t_type_code.Date,
       t_type_code.Des AS Type_D,
       t_cat_code.Des AS Cat_D,
       t_sub_code.Des AS Sub_Cat_D
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.Type=t2.Code) AS t_type_code
  JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.cat=t2.Code) AS t_cat_code
                                                      ON t_type_code.id=t_cat_code.id
  JOIN 
     (SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.Sub_Cat=t2.Code) AS t_sub_code
                                                      ON t_cat_code.id=t_sub_code.id
```